# Use @timestamp as metric in an elastic dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**Problem**

I am trying to build a dashboard in elastic with a table to monitor job runs.

I want to have per run the minimum timestamp (ie. job start) and the number of processed messages. The minimum timestamp is my problem, I can't seem to get it.

**What I have done**

All my log lines have as (relevant) fields: `@timestamp`, `nb_messages`, `run_id`. `run_id` is unique per run, and a run creates multiple log lines.

I create a dashboard, add a TSVB panel, and select Table.

I use `run_id` as the field to group by.

I can use `max(nb_message)` in my table without issue.

But if I use `min(@timestamp)`, or any other aggregation than `count`, I just get a `-`.

[image: dashboard with error]
I first tried with a lens instead of a TSVB panel, and I had the same issue, but with as message: `To use this function, select a different field`.

I can confirm in the index that logging.timestamp has date for type.

**Question**

Is there a way to use the timestamp as metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a "normal" data table visualization (navigate through *Aggregation based* option in the Visualization menu if you're using the latest version of Kibana) instead of the TSVB. There, the default metric is *count* representing the amount of events of the index pattern in the selected time range. You can use the **min** metric on the *@timestamp* field and aggregate/group your data as you want.

[image]

The preliminary is of course that the selected index pattern contains an @timestamp field.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: apt-get install thank you. I am still a bit confused by why it is possible there but not in other visualizations which feels kinda the same, but it works.

Comment: @Guillaume yes TSVB behaves somewhat different. Glad I could help you!